# Detect words from dictionary and convert to upper case?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dictionary

I have a dictionary

```
My_dict={'RED':'fruit', 'BLUE':'fish', 'GREEN':'colur'}
```

And a dataframe Df is

```
Col1| Col2|
|:--------|:-------|
|12| There are red trees in the forest|
|13|The sky is BLUE|
|14|The grasses are Green|
```

I need to check if the words in the dataframe match with keys and if it matches the convert to upper case

Df is

```
Col1| Col2|
|:--------|:-------|
|12| There are RED trees in the forest|
|13|The sky is BLUE|
|14|The grasses are GREEN|
```

Comment: post your attempt

Answer (score 0):

One approach:

```
df["Col2"] = df["Col2"].str.replace(rf"(?i)\b({'|'.join(map(str.lower, my_dict))})\b", repl=lambda x: x.group().upper(), regex=True)
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
   Col1                               Col2
0    12  There are RED trees in the forest
1    13                    The sky is BLUE
2    14              The grasses are GREEN
```

As an alternative use the `case` argument (as suggested by @jezrael):

```
df["Col2"].str.replace(rf"\b({'|'.join(map(str.lower, my_dict))})\b", repl=lambda x: x.group().upper(), regex=True, case=False)
```

Comment: Simplier `df["Col2"] = df["Col2"].str.replace(rf"\b({'|'.join(My_dict)})\b", repl=lambda x: x.group().upper(), regex=True, case=False)`